# How do I install a2ps for better printing?

Tags: bash, printing

How do I install this program so that I can do postscript printing?

Currently I get `-bash: a2ps: command not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have homebrew so the solution for me was:

```
brew install a2ps
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, first you'll want to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) on your Mac.  This allows you to easily install new command-line applications.

Then, just use the following terminal command:

```
sudo port install a2ps
```

Comment: +1 for useful info.  However macports is older and has issues so I use homebrew and thus have given my answer as that.

Comment: Macports is constantly updated so older does not mean less up to date. It did start earlier